# Insert page break in jinja2 for loop so that data prints on separate pages in a single pdf document using html2pdf

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, jinja2, jspdf, html2pdf

How can I write following data into separate pages in a single PDF document?

```
 <div id="result">
    {% for a, b, c in variable -%}
<div><strong>Label1:</strong> {{ a }} </div>
    <div><strong>Label2:</strong> {{ b }} </div>
    <div><strong>Label3:</strong> {{ c }} </div>
{%- endfor %}
</div>
```

The above data can contain hundreds of records. 
So, basically, I want to print each record on a different page in a single pdf document.

As per html2pdf official documentation, adding a class `html2pdf__page-break` to a div yields page break:
https://github.com/GoodJeans/html2pdf

I tried doing something like this, but then printing pdf yields blank pages:

```
    <div id="result">
        {% for a, b, c in variable -%}
    <div><strong>Label1:</strong> {{ a }} </div>
        <div><strong>Label2:</strong> {{ b }} </div>
        <div><strong>Label3:</strong> {{ c }} </div>
** <div class="html2pdf__page-break"></div>** <!-- Adding this class right here yields blank pdf 
I was thinking to insert page break here-->
    {%- endfor %}
    </div>
```

My html2pdf code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('result');
         html2pdf(element, {
         margin:       [1, 2.5, 1, 2], 
         image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1},
         html2canvas: {scale: 2}
});
```

Comment: for chrome I'm using `style='page-break-before:always'` on a block element, will post once I figure out how to incorporate this into jinja